# Eloquent JS Exercise (Ch.18 Q. 2)

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I was hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong... There's this exercise in the Eloquent JS book that asks you to write some code that can suggest words/values to users as they type... The code I've written is below. What happens is that when I run the code, the div element's text content changes to the wrong value. Specifically, it's set to a string of all the elements inside the array 'terms'. I really cant figure out why this happens!

```
    <input type="text" id="field">
<div id="suggestions" style="cursor: pointer"></div>

<script>
  // Builds up an array with global variable names, like
  // 'alert', 'document', and 'scrollTo'
  var terms = [];
  for (var name in window)
    terms.push(name);
  var input = document.querySelector('input');
  var div = document.querySelector('#suggestions');

input.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  var last = input.value.lastIndexOf(" ")+1;
  var check = input.value.slice(last);
  var reg = new RegExp(check);
  for (var i=0; i<terms.length; i++) {
    if (reg.test(terms[i])) {
      var text = document.createTextNode(terms[i]);
      div.appendChild(text)};
  };
})

</script>
```

Comment: You'll need to describe what the problem is. When you run the code what happens and what did you expect instead? Do you see error messages in the console?

Comment: For a start I'm thinking that `input.addEventListener("input"` should perhaps be something like `input.addEventListener("keyup"`.

Comment: When I try to test the code, the text inside the div element changes to a string of all the elements inside the terms array for some reason, i.e. this is the value that it sets to (the first bit of it at least) = locationexternal__sandbox__setIntervalsetIntervalrequestAnimationFramedivacacheslocalStoragesessionStoragewebkitStorageInfoappl

Comment: I hope the above comment makes it a bit more clear, thank you so much for the quick reply btw!

Comment: Andy, thanks for your suggestion. The reason I used input was because it is what the author suggests to do it the hints he provides for the exercise. Also, just in case this is useful, here is the link to the page with the exercise http://eloquentjavascript.net/18_forms.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you forgot to clean the div before each change in the input.
I also added a space after each word to make the output more readable.

```js
// Builds up an array with global variable names, like
// 'alert', 'document', and 'scrollTo'
var terms = [];
for (var name in window)
    terms.push(name);
var input = document.querySelector('input');
var div = document.querySelector('#suggestions');

input.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  div.innerHTML = '';
  var last = input.value.lastIndexOf(" ")+1;
  var check = input.value.slice(last);
  var reg = new RegExp(check);
  for (var i=0; i<terms.length; i++) {
    if (reg.test(terms[i])) {
      var text = document.createTextNode(terms[i] + ' ');
      div.appendChild(text)};
  };
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="field">
<div id="suggestions" style="cursor: pointer"></div>
```

With this code, you will display the name of the properties from the window object that contains the last word from the input. Try it writting "window location document". Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: I've added the changes you've suggested to my code. Yet still, when I type any letter in the input box, the div element's text content changes to the following (this is only a snippet of it, as the entire text is very long)= location external __sandbox __setInterval setInterval requestAnimationFrame diva caches localStorage sessionStorage webkitStorageInfo applicationCache

Comment: You can test the code directly in my answer too. If you enter the string "loc" in the input, you will have some suggestions (like "location localStorage locationbar" for my browser). Reading your question, this behaviour seems correct to me. What output do you expect?

Comment: ahh yes!! It works now. I was testing it by typing in a single letter, which obviously set the div to a large number of property names, making it seem like an error was occurring... thanks for your help!!  :)